# how can I sort a field form an Endnote Export File format where the Line contains GRAZ in the address as first line?

Tags: bash, unix-text-processing

I have a Endote Export File, looking like this:

```
    %0 Journal Article
    %A Abu-Rous, M.
    %A Ingolic, E.
    %A Schuster, K. C.
    %D 2006
    %Z Cellulose
    Article
    CODEN: CELLE
    %+ Christian Doppler-Laboratory of Fibre and Textile Chemistry in Cellulosics, Institute of Texile Chemistry and Textile Physics, Leopold-Franzens-University Innsbruck, Hoechsterstrasse 73, A-6850 Dornbirn, Austria
    Research Institute for Electron Microscopy (FELMI), Technical University of Graz, A-8010 Graz, Austria
    Textile Innovation, Lenzing AG, A-4860 Lenzing, Austria
    Schuster, K.C.; Textile Innovation, , A-4860 Lenzing, Austria; email: c.schuster@lenzing.com
    %~ Scopus
    %G English
    
    
    
    %0 Journal Article
    %P 5003-5011
    %! Ursolic acid from Trailliaedoxa gracilis induces apoptosis in medullary thyroid carcinoma cells
    %@ 17912997
    %R 10.3892/mmr.2015.4053
    %1 in_author_address; 
    %F 8
    %K Apoptosis
    Bioactive agents
    %Z Mol. Med. Rep.
    Article
    Chemicals/CAS: caspase 8; ursolic acid, 77-52-1; I kappa B kinase, 209902-66-9; Antineoplastic Agents, Phytogenic; Caspase 8; I-kappa B Kinase; IKBKG protein, human; Plant Extracts; Triterpenes; ursolic acid
    Tradenames: cpt, Sigma Aldrich; rotichrom, karlsruhe, Germany
    %+ Department of Pathophysiology and Immunology, Center of Molecular Medicine, Medical University of Graz, 31a Heinrichstrasse, Graz A, 8010, Austria
    Department of Biochemistry and Molecular Biology, Shanghai Medical School, Fudan University, Shanghai, 200433, China
    Department of Pharmacognosy, Institute of Pharmacy, Center of Molecular Biosciences, Leopold Franzens University of Innsbruck, Innsbruck A, 6010, Austria
    Core Unit of Biomedical Research, Division of Laboratory Animal Science and Genetics, Medical University of Vienna, Himberg A, 2325, Austria
    Research Institute for Electron Microscopy and Fine Structure Research, University of Technology Graz, Graz A, 8010, Austria
    Pfragner, R.; Department of Pathophysiology and Immunology, 31a Heinrichstrasse, Austria; email: roswitha.pfragner@medunigraz.at
    %~ Scopus C2 - 26151624
    %G English
```

the field beginning with **%+** contains the Author Address which could consits of more lines according the author addresses (1 to n relationship)  of the authors.
Each authore address are separated by a newline (linebreak)

Now I would like to ask how I can sort this field by the lines where GRAZ are in the line.
this lines where Graz are in it, they should be the first line in the listing.

Is there a way to do this by bash text processing tools, or need I write a Delphi`s programm to access and import the endnote Export dump.

The output of this example above should be

```
    %0 Journal Article
    %A Abu-Rous, M.
    %A Ingolic, E.
    %A Schuster, K. C.
    %D 2006
    %Z Cellulose
    Article
    CODEN: CELLE
    %+ Research Institute for Electron Microscopy (FELMI), Technical University of Graz, A-8010 Graz, Austria
    Christian Doppler-Laboratory of Fibre and Textile Chemistry in Cellulosics, Institute of Texile Chemistry and Textile Physics, Leopold-Franzens-University Innsbruck, Hoechsterstrasse 73, A-6850 Dornbirn, Austria
    Textile Innovation, Lenzing AG, A-4860 Lenzing, Austria
    Schuster, K.C.; Textile Innovation, , A-4860 Lenzing, Austria; email: c.schuster@lenzing.com
    %~ Scopus
    %G English
    
    
    
    %0 Journal Article
    %P 5003-5011
    %! Ursolic acid from Trailliaedoxa gracilis induces apoptosis in medullary thyroid carcinoma cells
    %@ 17912997
    %R 10.3892/mmr.2015.4053
    %1 in_author_address; 
    %F 8
    %K Apoptosis
    Bioactive agents
    %Z Mol. Med. Rep.
    Article
    Chemicals/CAS: caspase 8; ursolic acid, 77-52-1; I kappa B kinase, 209902-66-9; Antineoplastic Agents, Phytogenic; Caspase 8; I-kappa B Kinase; IKBKG protein, human; Plant Extracts; Triterpenes; ursolic acid
    Tradenames: cpt, Sigma Aldrich; rotichrom, karlsruhe, Germany
    %+ Department of Pathophysiology and Immunology, Center of Molecular Medicine, Medical University of Graz, 31a Heinrichstrasse, Graz A, 8010, Austria
    Department of Biochemistry and Molecular Biology, Shanghai Medical School, Fudan University, Shanghai, 200433, China
    Department of Pharmacognosy, Institute of Pharmacy, Center of Molecular Biosciences, Leopold Franzens University of Innsbruck, Innsbruck A, 6010, Austria
    Core Unit of Biomedical Research, Division of Laboratory Animal Science and Genetics, Medical University of Vienna, Himberg A, 2325, Austria
    Research Institute for Electron Microscopy and Fine Structure Research, University of Technology Graz, Graz A, 8010, Austria
    Pfragner, R.; Department of Pathophysiology and Immunology, 31a Heinrichstrasse, Austria; email: roswitha.pfragner@medunigraz.at
    %~ Scopus C2 - 26151624
    %G English
```

I would be happy and thankful for any interesting advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nocasematch            # make the match case-insensitive

# print the arrays and empty them
flush() {
    printf "%s" "%+ "
    printf "%s\n" "${out1[@]}" "${out2[@]}"
    out1=(); out2=()
}

while IFS= read -r line; do     # read the file line by line
    if (( auth )); then         # now in the "Author Address" context
        if [[ $line = "%"* ]]; then
                                # end of the "Author Address" context
            auth=0
            flush               # print the arrays
            echo "$line"        # print current line
        else
            [[ $line = *"GRAZ"* ]] && out1+=("$line") || out2+=("$line")
                                # if the line contains "GRAZ" store it in the array out1, else out2
        fi
    else
        if [[ $line = "%+"* ]]; then
            auth=1              # enter in the "Author Address" context
            [[ $line = *"GRAZ"* ]] && out1+=("${line:3}") || out2+=("${line:3}")
                                # ${line:3} removes leading 3 characters
        else
            echo "$line"
        fi
    fi
done < input_file
```

Output:

```
%1 Journal Article
%A Abu-Rous, M.
%A Ingolic, E.
%A Schuster, K. C.
%D 2006
%Z Cellulose
Article
CODEN: CELLE
%+ Research Institute for Electron Microscopy (FELMI), Technical University of Graz, A-8010 Graz, Austria
Christian Doppler-Laboratory of Fibre and Textile Chemistry in Cellulosics, Institute of Texile Chemistry and Textile Physics, Leopold-Franzens-University Innsbruck, Hoechsterstrasse 73, A-6850 Dornbirn, Austria
Textile Innovation, Lenzing AG, A-4860 Lenzing, Austria
Schuster, K.C.; Textile Innovation, , A-4860 Lenzing, Austria; email: c.schuster@lenzing.com
%~ Scopus
%G English



%0 Journal Article
%P 5003-5011
%! Ursolic acid from Trailliaedoxa gracilis induces apoptosis in medullary thyroid carcinoma cells
%@ 17912997
%R 10.3892/mmr.2015.4053
%1 in_author_address;
%F 8
%K Apoptosis
Bioactive agents
%Z Mol. Med. Rep.
Article
Chemicals/CAS: caspase 8; ursolic acid, 77-52-1; I kappa B kinase, 209902-66-9; Antineoplastic Agents, Phytogenic; Caspase 8; I-kappa B Kinase; IKBKG protein, human; Plant Extracts; Triterpenes; ursolic acid
Tradenames: cpt, Sigma Aldrich; rotichrom, karlsruhe, Germany
%+ Department of Pathophysiology and Immunology, Center of Molecular Medicine, Medical University of Graz, 31a Heinrichstrasse, Graz A, 8010, Austria
Research Institute for Electron Microscopy and Fine Structure Research, University of Technology Graz, Graz A, 8010, Austria
Pfragner, R.; Department of Pathophysiology and Immunology, 31a Heinrichstrasse, Austria; email: roswitha.pfragner@medunigraz.at
Department of Biochemistry and Molecular Biology, Shanghai Medical School, Fudan University, Shanghai, 200433, China
Department of Pharmacognosy, Institute of Pharmacy, Center of Molecular Biosciences, Leopold Franzens University of Innsbruck, Innsbruck A, 6010, Austria
Core Unit of Biomedical Research, Division of Laboratory Animal Science and Genetics, Medical University of Vienna, Himberg A, 2325, Austria
%~ Scopus C2 - 26151624
%G English
```

The output slightly differs from your expected output, one is because the `... University of Technology Graz ...` line comes later than other lines which do not contain `GRAZ` in your expected result, the other is because `medunigraz` is considered to match `GRAZ`.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Please could you also show me, what it need to be done when only these author_address lines (%+ ) should be outputed, which has GRAZ (case insentive) in it? I assume that this line `printf "%s\n" "${out1[@]}" "${out2[@]}"` need to be change to this: `printf "%s\n" "${out1[@]}" `

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If you want to print the author address lines
only which contain `GRAZ`, drop `"${out2[@]}"` in the flush() function
as `printf "%s\n" "${out1[@]}"`.

Comment: Great ! Very Very great. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good to know it works. If you feel your problem is solved, I'd appreciate if you accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.